# Include line breaks in Google Sheets cells when getting form responses from Google Forms

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, line-breaks, array-formulas

I am wondering if anyone can help with this. I am creating a merged document using HTTP Post via Infusionsoft from a Google Form Response. The HTTP Post automatically pulls the data from Infusionsoft and posts it to the Google Form which then adds it to a Google sheet. I am then using Autocrat to automatically create a letter.

I have managed to make all this work, however, the one issue that I am having is that some of the form entries are paragraph text (so, for instance, the body of the letter, which has several paragraphs). When I pull this data into the sheet once the HTTP post has fired, the text within that cell separates the paragraphs with `<br><br>`. So, for example, it would be:

```
"Paragraph one.<br><br>
 Paragraph two.<br><br>" etc.
```

This then merges into the letter with the `<br><br>` rather than line breaks.

I want it to appear within the merged letter as:

```
"Paragraph one.

Paragraph two."
```

within the cell. Ie with line breaks.

Is this possible? Have found another post with this function, but this is the opposite of what I want to achieve.

```
function lineBreakTest() {
  var cellWithLineBreaks = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("q3").getValue();
  Logger.log(cellWithLineBreaks);

  cellWithLineBreaks = cellWithLineBreaks.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');

  Logger.log(cellWithLineBreaks);

  // Post to your Google Site here. Logger.log is just used to demonstrate.

}
```

I would also want it to apply to the whole column, so whenever autocrat runs and a new row is added, it would apply the same function.

Would this all happen automatically also?

Any help would be amazing.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: I have stripped back the other fields on this spreadsheet (for data protection stuff) and just left the two where I am having the issue.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zPDTZWg-7tu4Scx9-IIZjtqO-BpV52phllNBuSCU64g/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Row two is where I have manually added the line breaks. Row 3 is where they have been imported from the form response, where the line breaks have changed to <br><br>. This is what I want to remove and replace with a line break as in row 2. Problem is that it needs to happen automatically on import from the form response. Is it possible to do? Row 2 merges into the letter correctly with paragraphs. Row 3 does not. It just includes the <br><br> as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this solution if it fits you:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(A:B, "<br><br>", CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)))
```

[image: 0]

...then you can just hide A:B columns

[image: 0]

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you so much. Amazing. It's exactly what I needed. Thank you.